# HighCharts: Multiple X and Y Axis tooltip doesn't appear (custom formatter)

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts, angular-highcharts

I am working on a chart having multiple x and y axis. Data series is linked to these  x and y axis. I have a tooltip which is shared and uses html and custom formatter. Below is the configuration of tooltip:

```
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
      shared: true,
      split: false,
      followPointer: true,
      outside: true,
      formatter: myTTFormatter
```

myTTFormatter gets the points array and I am able to get tooltip as well, but the problem is it appears for only the first series and when I hover over other series it doesn't show up. I put a debugger to custom formatter fn and it goes there as well, but I don't understand why the tooltip is not appearing when I hover over other series in my chart.
Note: I have linked all other xAxis to the first XAxis to make the zoom work for all the data series.

HighCharts version: 9.1.2

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thanks for helping. Please take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-rj5jen?file=src/app/app.component.ts When I hover over first series I can see tool tip, but as I take the mouse pointer to second series, it goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing a part of your code. I minimalized your code and it looks like a regression. This issue is already reported on the Highcharts Github issue channel and seems that is in process of working on that: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16004

Mnimalized demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8jke1yvc/

If you don't need any of the new features use the previous version of the Highcharts: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8osj6ch9/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/8/highstock.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. It worked in 8.2.2. version. But now the date picker is not appearing. Any Idea when this fix will be included in to the latest version?

Comment: @Ritesh you should ask the core developers in the thread on Github.